# Inserting space/gaps between floating tables

Tags: html, css

I am using float in css to display multiple tables vertically next to one another however float puts them without any spacing in between. How can I insert some gaps betwen these tables?

```
table{
    float: left;
    border:none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shall use the margin property

```
table
{
     margin:0 10px;
}
```

For info, the 0 corresponds to the above and under margin, and the 10 for the left and right margin.

You could also write it like margin(0 10px 0 10px); which stands for up - right - bottom - left

Comment: I guess this `margin` is refered to affect margin of table (outside)... Guess that the right way for doing this is somethng like `cellspacing="10` inside table tag

Comment: It depends what he want, cellspacing will provide space in each cell, but wont make the tables not touching eachother

Answer (score 0):

here you can use the {display:inline} instead of float
or you can use the padding or margin between tables/elements

Answer (score 0):

```
table{
display: inline;
border:none;
border-collapse: collapse;
margin:0px 0px 0px 10px
```

}

Comment: Please add a couple of clarifying statements and, if possible, links to relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/56EBH/2/)

**HTML**

```
<table border="1" class="table1">
    <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
        <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
        <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table border="1" class="table2">
    <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
        <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
        <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.table1 {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
    background: red;
}
.table2 {
    float: left;
    background: blue;
}
```

**NOTE:** I made table1 with `margin-right` - this will separate from table2. If you have more them 2 tables, add `margin-right` in left tables, or `margin-left` in right tables.